# OpenAPI gradle generator - adding custom template

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

How to add additional files to the generated package?

Let's say I want to add AUTHORS.md file to the root of the generated package.
CLI allows to specify "files" node in config.yaml that can be passed as an argument to cli generator as described here: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/

but can't find equivalent setting for gradle generator.